# Why does is_array() return false?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, simplexml

I have this SimpleXML object:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#176 (1) {
 ["record"]=>
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#39 (2) {
     ["f"]=>
     array(2) {
       [0]=>
       string(13) "stuff"
       [1]=>
       string(1) "1"
     }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#37 (2) {
    ["f"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "more stuff"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "90"
    }
  }
}
```

Why does is_array($object->record) return false? It clearly says it's an array. Why can't I detect it using is_array?

Also, I am unable to cast it as an array using (array) $object->record. I get this error:

> Warning:  It is not yet possible to
>   assign complex types to properties

Comment: Do not ever trust `var_dump()` or `print_r()` with SimpleXML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SimpleXML nodes are objects that can contain other SimpleXML nodes. Use `iterator_to_array().`

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it allowed to me to accomplish my task. Thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an array. The `var_dump` output is misleading. Consider:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<foo>
 <bar>a</bar>
 <bar>b</bar>
</foo>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
var_dump($xml);
var_dump($xml->bar);
?>
```

Output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["bar"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
  }
}

object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
}
```

As you can see by the second `var_dump`, it is actually a `SimpleXMLElement`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem using `count()` function:

```
if( count( $xml ) > 1 ) {
    // $xml is an array...
}
```